# FI_Init_FreeType variable declaration error

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program that uses freetype.

code :

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
int main()
{
FT_Library library;
int error = FI_Init_FreeType(&library);
}
```

i am compiling as g++ try1_c++demo.cpp -I/usr/include/freetype2

it gives following error:

```
try1_c++demo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try1_c++demo.cpp:9: error: ‘FI_Init_FreeType’ was not declared in this scope
```

how do i solve this error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FT_Init_FreeType`?

Comment: I hope your program will render fonts better than whatever you have right now...

Comment: hey thanks for quick reply.
i changed to FT_Init_FreeType.

but now it give this error:
/tmp/ccZmMseG.o: In function `main':
try1_c++demo.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

now wht to do??

Comment: forgot to add `-l<whatever-the-name-of-freetype.so>` to your linker? You should learn to use the linker and more about linking static libraries. Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312034/c-compiler-error-undefined-reference-to-ft-init-freetype?lq=1

Comment: i did this: g++ try1_c++demo.cpp -I/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/lib/libfreetype.so

also tried that link
still same error...

Comment: Please read the man pages of ld http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld
-L means path to the libraries, -l actually links the library. You need to add -lfreetype and make sure libfreetype.so is located in /usr/lib. Also note that there is a difference between `-I` and `-l` (the first one is capital i (from the word include) and last on is lowercase L (from the word library))

Comment: as u told i used this: g++ try1_c++demo.cpp -I/usr/include/freetype2 -L/usr/lib -lfreetype

and it compiled
Thanks a lot for help!!
i will try to learn to use linker..

Comment: You usually may omit `-L/usr/lib`, it's the default search path.