# How to include freetype library to Keil uVision 4?

Tags: embedded, static-libraries, truetype, freetype, keil

I have to add freetype library to keil uvision 4 for dealing ttf font files.
I followed the steps in [Simple Glyph Loading Tutorial](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html).

I am trying to compile the code below called [example1.c](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example1.c). I tried the tutorial in Ubuntu terminal with the help of [Undefined reference to 'FT_Init_FreeType'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312034/c-compiler-error-undefined-reference-to-ft-init-freetype). It compiled without error.

But unfortunately I don't know how to link the library to keil. 
It shows "Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol FT_Init_FreeType (referred from example1.o)."

Can anyone help me?

---

***example1.c***:

```
/* example1.c                                                      */
/*                                                                 */
/* This small program shows how to print a rotated string with the */
/* FreeType 2 library.                                             */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H    

#define WIDTH   640
#define HEIGHT  480    

/* origin is the upper left corner */
unsigned char image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];    

/* Replace this function with something useful. */

void
draw_bitmap( FT_Bitmap*  bitmap,
             FT_Int      x,
             FT_Int      y)
{
  FT_Int  i, j, p, q;
  FT_Int  x_max = x + bitmap->width;
  FT_Int  y_max = y + bitmap->rows;    

  for ( i = x, p = 0; i < x_max; i++, p++ )
  {
    for ( j = y, q = 0; j < y_max; j++, q++ )
    {
      if ( i < 0      || j < 0       ||
           i >= WIDTH || j >= HEIGHT )
        continue;

      image[j][i] |= bitmap->buffer[q * bitmap->width + p];
    }
  }
}    

void
show_image( void )
{
  int  i, j;

  for ( i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++ )
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++ )
      putchar( image[i][j] == 0 ? ' '
                                : image[i][j] < 128 ? '+'
                                                    : '*' );
    putchar( '\n' );
  }
}

int
main( int     argc,
      char**  argv )
{
  FT_Library    library;
  FT_Face       face;

  FT_GlyphSlot  slot;
  FT_Matrix     matrix;                 /* transformation matrix */
  FT_Vector     pen;                    /* untransformed origin  */
  FT_Error      error;

  char*         filename;
  char*         text;

  double        angle;
  int           target_height;
  int           n, num_chars;

  if ( argc != 3 )
  {
    fprintf ( stderr, "usage: %s font sample-text\n", argv[0] );
    exit( 1 );
  }

  filename      = argv[1];                           /* first argument     */
  text          = argv[2];                           /* second argument    */
  num_chars     = strlen( text );
  angle         = ( 25.0 / 360 ) * 3.14159 * 2;      /* use 25 degrees     */
  target_height = HEIGHT;

  error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );              /* initialize library */
  /* error handling omitted */

  error = FT_New_Face( library, filename, 0, &face );/* create face object */
  /* error handling omitted */

  /* use 50pt at 100dpi */
  error = FT_Set_Char_Size( face, 50 * 64, 0,
                            100, 0 );                /* set character size */
  /* error handling omitted */

  slot = face->glyph;

  /* set up matrix */
  matrix.xx = (FT_Fixed)( cos( angle ) * 0x10000L );
  matrix.xy = (FT_Fixed)(-sin( angle ) * 0x10000L );
  matrix.yx = (FT_Fixed)( sin( angle ) * 0x10000L );
  matrix.yy = (FT_Fixed)( cos( angle ) * 0x10000L );

  /* the pen position in 26.6 cartesian space coordinates; */
  /* start at (300,200) relative to the upper left corner  */
  pen.x = 300 * 64;
  pen.y = ( target_height - 200 ) * 64;

  for ( n = 0; n < num_chars; n++ )
  {
    /* set transformation */
    FT_Set_Transform( face, &matrix, &pen );

    /* load glyph image into the slot (erase previous one) */
    error = FT_Load_Char( face, text[n], FT_LOAD_RENDER );
    if ( error )
      continue;                 /* ignore errors */

    /* now, draw to our target surface (convert position) */
    draw_bitmap( &slot->bitmap,
                 slot->bitmap_left,
                 target_height - slot->bitmap_top );

    /* increment pen position */
    pen.x += slot->advance.x;
    pen.y += slot->advance.y;
  }

  show_image();

  FT_Done_Face    ( face );
  FT_Done_FreeType( library );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a linker error not a compiler error, it suggests that you have not linked the library.  How did you "*add freetype library*", and have you linked it to your project.  You will have had to first build the library in any case from source.  The steps in the link you posted are insufficient to get FreeType working - It makes the reasonable assumption that you have a built and working library and know how to link to it.

Comment: What you should do is add the missing information to your question so that it can be answered and stops getting down-votes.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the suggestion.  Updated the question now. Is it clear?

Comment: @Clifford I could do the project using freetype amalgamate files. :)

Comment: Here is the answer provided by ElectronicsKing: [Here is step by step video on how to add library in keil uVision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLQqFP_JTZk). It was deleted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project "freetype".  In the project settings change the "Output" to a static library:
[image]

Add the freetype sources to the project, and build.  Do not use your "amalgamated" source file - that will destroy the library granularity and lead to excessively large code.

Add the resulting freetype.lib file to your application project.  The linker will select only those modules from the library that are necessary to resolve references in your application thus keeping size to a minimum.

You may get smaller code size from including the freetype source directly in your application and using cross-module optimisation (this will work regardless of the use of separate compilation or the amalgamated file); however the build time may be excessive as it requires repeated full-builds to fully optimise.  Note that unlike compiler-optimisation, cross-module optimisation does not affect the debugging experience - you can use the debugger normally even with it enabled.

**EDIT** : 
The cross-module optimisation feature may not apply when using the GNU toolchain; it refers to the use of Keil MDK-ARM which uses ARM's RealView toolchain.  Other aspects of this answer may also be applicable only to MDK-ARM.

Comment: Hello @Clifford ,
I followed your steps. I could create a lib output from keil project.
I included the lib file into another project. 
But on compilation ,it shows some error like these...
".\lib\SDK_AMP.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol autofit_module_class (referred from ftinit.o)."
".\lib\SDK_AMP.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol bdf_driver_class (referred from ftinit.o)."

any idea?

Comment: Since these are linker errors, then compilation must have been successful.  It looks like the library you have created is incomplete.

Comment: Hello @Clifford ..,
Thank you for your support. But I couldn't understand why the library is incomplete.

Comment: In the case of the two longer errors you have mentioned, then the source file ftinit.c is missing from your library.  The FreeTypeAlmalgam.c file in-lines 153 separate .c source files - those are the files you need to add to your project - adding the .h header files is optional.

Comment: Hello @Clifford... , Done... !!! Actually, when I was compiling from the complete source, it displayed compilation errors in a huge number . So I followed this link [link](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/freetype/2012-04/msg00024.html). But the missing definitions were not in the included files. I found the definitions in 'autofit' and 'smooth' directories . So added them. It cleared the error. Printed Output obtained. The Previous bin size (From amalgamated source) was 410KB. Now it is 260 KB . Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello @Clifford...,  I have a doubt.  When I compiles the example1.c in Ubuntu from the  freetype library, it results a binary of size 14 KB.  But when I compiles the same example1.c in Keil uVision 5 , it results a binary of size 260 KB. We can subtract 70 KB of ttf file as header(in Ubuntu  it was from the file system ) and 70 KB as basic machine codes. The rest 120 KB is for freetype codes. I cannot understand the situation. What do u think?

Comment: In Ubuntu presumably the FreeType library is a shared library (along with any other system-level dependencies in your code) and not *statically linked* as it necessarily is in the embedded system.  You are not comparing apples with apples.  Take a look for example at the memory footprint of your process in the Gnome System Monitor while it is running to get a truer picture of its size.  Scalable font support in an embedded system was never going to be cheap!

Comment: @jww : Your comment should perhaps be applied to the question rather then my answer.

Comment: @Clifford - Yes, sorry about that. I intended to add it under the question... When is Stack overflow going to provide a process to migrate an answer to a comment???

Answer (score 1):

After a long research I could find an alternate solution for the problem. I could reach at freetype amalgamate project, which one is the exact solution for this . 
Here all the source files are amalgamated into two files. One ".c" file and one ".h" file. So it can be easily integrate into any other project.

Here is the link for [freetype amalgamate](https://github.com/vinniefalco/FreeTypeAmalgam?files=1).

Thank you.

Comment: I see very little point in that, and many potential problems - separate compilation and linking was all that was required.  Note that unless you use cross-module optimisation, linking a single amalgamated source rather then building a static library from the separate files may lead to larger than necessary executables.  In the long term you'd have done better spending the month learning to do it properly.

Comment: @Clifford You are right. My current problem is to reduce the bin size. That is a good suggestion. Thank you once again. I will try again to compile from separate source files.

Comment: Simply adding the separate source files to your code may have no effect on the size.  You need to enable cross-module optimisation.  When you do this the linker generates a feedback file that records all the unused functions, then when the compiler next compiles it omits these functions.  Unfortunately it requires full and repeated builds to get full optimisation; (uVision5 does that automatically so builds take a long time).  The alternative is to add the sources to a separate static-link library project, generate a genuine static library, then link that to your application project.

Comment: @Clifford okay. I am trying to generate a static library from the sources for arm-none-gnu-eabi toolchain. Is it correct?

Comment: Ah - you should have mentioned in your question you were using the GNU toolchain - that makes the fact that you are using Keil uVision almost entirely irrelevant.  I assumed you were also using the Keil toolchain (MDK-ARM).  That probably makes any comments about cross-module optimisation irrelevant.